# Run script stored in text editor/blend file from CLI

Tags: python, command-line, text-editor

What is the correct way to run a script internally stored in the blend file from the CLI?

I'm trying to run a script I have in the text editor. I have it named "Import" in the text editor. The `-P` parameter seems to be made for externally stored scripts and doesn't work when I try to use it like this `blender -b file.blend -P Import`.

I would prefer to leave the script in the blend file. But if necessary I can move it out.

I've read that you can start a script when you load a blend file but that won't work for me. I am setting up a video render server where I will be importing video files into the VSE and generating proxy files from the "Import" script. The proxy render takes a long time so I am looking to offload that to the server. I will then be downloading the blend file and proxy files to another computer to do editing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `blender --help` and look for any option with 'Python' in the name. You'll find that it's `blender filename.blend --python-text Import`.

Alternatively, name your script `yourscript.py` (so end it in `.py`), and you can enable the "Register" checkbox to automatically run the script whenever you load the blend file. This can be easier, depending on your needs.