# is it possible to write a script that renders an image in blender

Tags: scripting, blender-internal-render-engine

If i had an image on my computer which acts as a texture and an already created scene in blender which has a 3d object in it. Is it possible to write a blender script to take the image which resides in a location on my computer and use it as a texture on the 3d object in my blender scene, then render the scene and also save the rendered image in a location path on my pc ?

Comment: Yes it is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @cegaton none yet.  I wanted to know if it is possible before i start the process. I also want to know if  blender  GUI has to be running for the process to work ?

Comment: No, you don't need the GUI, you can do this running blender from terminal.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this would be to have a project whose textures point to a files with a known location. Replacing those files with new ones with the same name would take care of the textures.

Then just render using the command line.

```
blender -b file.blend -a
```

would render the animation with no GUI.

To set the output path use:

```
blender -b file.blend -a -o <path>
```

Read:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/workflows/command_line.html

and

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html

Comment: Read also:  [run-script-stored-in-text-editor-blend-file-from-cli](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91534/run-script-stored-in-text-editor-blend-file-from-cli) and [how-can-i-batch-render-multiple-blendfiles-consecutively](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74750/how-can-i-batch-render-multiple-blendfiles-consecutively/74757#74757)