# Disable/enable VSE via command line

Tags: rendering

Is it possible to enable or disable the "use Sequencer" checkbox via the CLI render command? There's no command line argument for that, but is there an easy way to decide at rendertime whether to use it or not? (Blender pre-2.8)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include a script in the CLI and include the folowing lines:

```
bpy.context.scene.render.use_sequencer = False
bpy.context.scene.render.render()
```

Use the `-P <filename>` switch to load desired python script.

Comment: Can that Python script also reside within the Blender file as a text block, so no external dependency is needed?

Comment: See [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91534/run-script-stored-in-text-editor-blend-file-from-cli)

Comment: Thanks! Solved my issue