# How to disable VSE for render?

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor

I have a video reference in my Video Sequence Editor while I animate my scene. However, when I try to render, it just renders the video file that's loaded in the VSE instead of my scene.
I'd like to just disable the VSE's influence over my render so I can have my reference there without affecting anything else. How could I do this?

Comment: In the post-processing section disable **sequencer**

Comment: Where is this option? I cannot find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the post-processing section disable sequencer

2.8x
[image]

2.7x
[image]

Comment: See also [disable-enable CSE via command line](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/155699/disable-enable-vse-via-command-line)